# Migrating custom tables from M1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.3, database, data-migration-tool

Data Migration Tool was used to migrate our Magento store from 1.9.2.2 to Magento 2.3.3 successfully. Upon inspection of the Magento 2 DB, I found out the custom tables weren't migrated which are 6 of them. Is there still a possibility of Data Migration Tool being used again to migrate these custom tables? Or is exporting and importing them a better approach?

Comment: This could be also be achieved by splitting the tables in the source. And then just let the migration-tool do its work,

Comment: @Yo Yo Roshan, but the data migration is already complete so I am looking for a way to bring in those custom tables from Magento 1 to Magento 2 DB. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can create those custom tables manually in Magento 2 and then map those fields and then do migration only for those custom tables. Note: take a backup of your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but It cannot done via Data migration as per as my idea.

I only for suggest

**create all 3column data on a another table from Magento.**

After data-migration,copy data from that table to using MYSQL

Ex :-

```
Table 1: id, name

Table 2: name, description
```

More Information refer this :-

**[Magento 2 Custom Table Migration - Split data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221401/magento-2-custom-table-migration-split-data)**

Comment: many say it cannot be done with data migration tool. But technically speaking migration tool should have taken care of this too.

Comment: yes you not create the migrate data migration tool. So you create the table column and try